# How to detect spring and fall in a monthly time series of NDVI data in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time-series of monthly mean NDVI-values for 18 years. I would like to estimate time points, which testify the start or the end of vegetation season. I already tried to use bfast, but this has not given me the result I am looking for. There should be to breakpoints in each year.

Are there any other R-packages which could help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a R-package called phenex, which provide a function named phenoPhase. You can estimate days of greening, browning and vegetation maximum with proportinally standard deviation.
Caution: daily ndvi data are required. So you may extrapolate your data.